# Nodejs max concurrent connections limited to 1012? (probably only on my machine xD)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So, I've been trying to test out my server code, but client sockets catch 'error' when 1012 connections have been established. Client simulator keeps trying 'til it's tried to connect as many times as I've told it to (obviously). Though, as stated, the server is unwilling to serve more than 1012 connections.

I'm running both client simulator & server on the same computer (might be dumb, but shouldn't it work anyway?).

(Running on socket.io)

Comment: If you're running on Linux the default max open files is only 1024 and each socket connection uses up a file descriptor.

Comment: Sounds like the source of the problem, though changing limit still gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the limit of open connection/files in Linux:

> ulimit -n 2048

Here is more info regarding [ulimit](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/tips%20and%20tricks/ulimit.htm)

Comment: You may need to edit /etc/security/limits.conf to allow your user to change the ulimit.